# How to convert an old JavaScript API to a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I've got an AWS call that looks like this:

```
ecs.describeServices(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
      return { data: '',success: false };
   } else {
      return { data: 'whohoo',success: true};
   }
});
```

This is in a method that needs to return a promise that resolves to my return object.

I've been experimenting with this type solution, but just can't figure it out.

```
        var keepsHisWord;
        keepsHisWord = true;
        var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if (keepsHisWord) {
                resolve({ mytest: "mytest101" });
            } else {
                reject("The man doesnt want to keep his word");
            }
        });
```

---

*Edit:*
Working. Thanks to the two people who posted. That really helped a lot.  And wondering why the question down-voted. I did a bunch of research first. I guess just not as smart at the down-voter.

```
            var promise1 = function(params) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                ecs.describeServices(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        resolve({
                            error: "my error"
                        });
                    } else {
                        resolve({
                            runningCount: data.services[0].runningCount,
                            pendingCount: data.services[0].pendingCount,
                            status: data.services[0].status,
                            desiredCount: data.services[0].desiredCount,
                            createdAt: data.services[0].desiredCount,
                            events: data.services[0].events
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        };
        return promise1(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your service call into promise:

```
promiseFunc = function(params) {


    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

        ecs.describeServices(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                resolve({ data: '',success: false });
            } else {
                reject({ data: 'whohoo',success: true});
            }
        });

    })

}
```

Then use it:

```
 promiseFunc(params).then(x => {})
```

Comment: I can get your example to work, my success method does get called (I can put console.log to see that).  In my api, I need to return the promise so I do "return promiseFunc(params);", but then my api seems to not know how to get the answer.  does the caller simply execute my .then function? If so, I tried promiseFunc(params).then(x => {return x.data;}) and got error still.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Node 8 there is a `util.promisify` function, which does exactly that

```
var util = require('util');
var describeServices = util.promisify(ecs.describeServices);
describeServices(params)
    .then()
    .catch()
```

You also can find many implementations of this function in the internet.

Comment: Thanks @Sergii, I don't think I quite get it. I added code I tried in the question above but without success.

Comment: You should return promise1 directly:
e.g. `return promise1.then().catch()` as `promise1` and `promise1.then()` are different promises

Comment: Thanks @Sergii but I'm still not getting it. I tried what I think you suggested (updated in question above) and my error condition hits (odd) and I get the error "TypeError: promise1.then is not a function"

Comment: Sorry, I meant `return promise1(params)
           .then((data) => {
                console.log(data.services[0].runningCount);
                return {
                    runningCount: data.services[0].runningCount
                };
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
                return {
                    runningCount: -1
                };
            });`
Does the error still appear?

Comment: that runs, and returns my error condition.  somehow, the parameters are not getting passed into ecs.describeServices.

Comment: I pasted above what I have.

Comment: Got it! thanks for the help. I posted my final above.